# How can I load only the latest saved image from the document directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to show the latest added image that I saved into my document directory.

In the code below I tried to first count all the images that are in ImageData.plist and then show the latest image by subtracting 1.

It doesn't show any image so I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out what exactly?

Thx in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Show latest added image from document directory
//Add UIImageView
UIImageView *guideSheet = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)]autorelease];

//Add latest image
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageData.plist"];
NSArray *plistFile = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSInteger plistCount = [plistFile count];

for (NSInteger i = plistCount; i < (plistCount - 1); i++) {

    // Show image
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ImageData/ImageData%i.jpg", i];
    UIImage* content = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
    guideSheet.image = content;
    [self.view addSubview:guideSheet];
}

[plistFile release];
```

}

Comment: Would you mind to add the tag for the language, which did you use? Thanks

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.2. I'm still a newbie so I hope this is the right information :)

Answer (score 0):

When you created the NSString object imageName, you did not append the documents directory location. Therefore, the full path of the image it's using is /ImageData/ImageData%i.jpg.

```
NSString *imageName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageData/ImageData%i.jpg", i];
```

Should work if you were able to save the images correctly into the documents directory (if these images are in the mainBundle, then you'll have to use pathForResource instead of the above).

Comment: If I use your code I get the issue: Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2.